# How to read/write data to a table which does not have a primary key using Entity Framwork

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm new to entire concept of ASP.NET MVC and Entity Framework and have been facing issues with reading data from an existing table which does not have a primary key.

Below are the tables in the database, and I guess they are not related to each other either. As I am not allowed to edit the existing tables, I am supposed to create a model class which compensates for the missing factors.

**dbo.SURVEY** : My applications only reads data from here.

```
int id [PK]
string title
```

**dbo.QUESTIONS** : My applications only reads data from here.

```
int survey_id
int id [PK]
string text
string question_type (stores string values which says whether the question is an MCQ or has Text response)
```

**dbo.OPTIONS** : My applications only reads data from here.

```
int ID [PK]
int question_id
string text
```

**dbo.ATTEMPTED_ANSWER** : My applications reads and writes data to this table based on user inputs.

```
int question_id
int answered_option_id (Has null values)
string answered_text
```

Below are my model classes for above tables.

```
public class SURVEY
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }

    public IList<QUESTIONS> Questions { get; set; }
}

public class QUESTIONS
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Survey")]
    public int survey_id { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public string answer_type { get; set; }

    public SURVEY Survey { get; set; }
    public IList<OPTIONS> Options { get; set; }
    public IList<ATTEMPTED_ANSWER> Attempted_Answers { get; set; }
}

public class OPTIONS
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Question")]
    public int question_id { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }

    public QUESTIONS Question { get; set; }
}

public class ATTEMPTED_ANSWER
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; } //has been created in the model does not exist in db

    [ForeignKey("Question")]
    public int question_id { get; set; }
    public int attempted_option_id { get; set; }
    public string attempted_text { get; set; }

    public QUESTIONS Question { get; set; }
}
```

This is what I have managed until now.

When I try to store all the entries related to a question by using the below code

````
var QuestionList =  _context.Questions
                            .Where(m => m.survey_id == id)
                            .Include(m => m.Options)
                            .Include(m => m.Attempted_Answers); //load question with related options and answers ```
````

I get an error:

> SqlException: Invalid column name 'id'.

It does not show an error for this code:

```
var QuestionList =  _context.Questions
                            .Where(m => m.survey_id == id)
                            .Include(m => m.Options)
```

I understand that the error has something to do with the id property, So can someone please help me solve the issue? Is there a way to load related data from database at the sametime autosetting the id property of my ATTEMPTED_ANSWER entity?

Comment: `public int id { get; set; } //has been created in the model does not exist in db` have you tried removing that property from the `ATTEMPTED_ANSWER` class?

Comment: You are comparing two fields of  a same table that's why it is showing the error.

Comment: It looks more like you should be using a compound key

Comment: A **properly designed** database schema should **always** have a primary key on any regular table (maybe not staging/temporary - but anything that's persisted long-term)

Comment: @FrancescoGimignano Yes, if I remove it, then too it throws an error saying that ATTEMPTED_ANSWER requires a Primary Key to be defined.

Comment: @RohanRao I'm sorry I was not able to completely understand your comment. 

What I'm trying to do is loading all questions, it's related options and answers (if already attempted by the user) in a single variable named QuestionList. 

The model Questions has 2 navigation properties list of options and list of attempted_answers and trying to populate these lists with the .Include(). I succeed when I load only options but face an error when I try to load attempted_answers along with options.

Comment: @CallumLinington I don't have the required fields for using them compound keys. in dbo.ATTEMPTED_ANSWER question_id has duplicate values and attempted_option_id has null values. So not sure how can I use a compound key here.

Comment: @marc_s Agreed, But right now I'm not supposed to change the table structure i the database. Hence I need to figure out a way in my code that does the required read/write operations at the same time supports existing db structure.

Comment: @RajinderNagi there's no "right now". ORMs require primary keys if you want to modify data. Without even a composite PK, you can't use *any* ORM.  In fact, you can't even write a SQL query yourself that guarantees that only one row will be updated. If there's a combination of columns that ensures uniqueness it should be uses as a PK. If not, you have a more serious problem already

Comment: Simply put, if you have two or more rows with the same values, which one are you going to update? Is it possible to have *more* than one attempted answer per question? If so, the primary key should be `question_id, attempted_option_id `. You can add the `Key` attribute on both properties. If only one answer is allowed, the key should be `question_id`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Agreed, Updating table without PK is huge risk. question_id cant be used a primary key either as it contains duplicate values. attempted_option_id has null values. Using them as composite key does not guarantee a correct update query either.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up creating a new table with a primary key. There's no definite work around for this situation that will allow you to effectively read and write data.